# Filtering nested array in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have scenario where i need to filter the array based on user input. Below is my json.

```
[
  {
    "storename": "store 1",
    "license": "12314",
    "books": [
      "abc",
      "def",
      "cdf"
    ]
  },
  {
    "storename": "store 2",
    "license": "12344",
    "books": [
      "dfd",
      "eww"
    ]
  },
  {
    "storename": "store 3",
    "license": "12344",
    "books": [

    ]
  }
]
```

I want to filter items of nested array, storename and license should always be returned, however books array will returned based on user input.

I tried using ko.utils.arrayFilter but no luck. For example if user searches for book abc output should be.

```
[
  {
    "storename": "store 1",
    "license": "12314",
    "books": [
      "abc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "storename": "store 2",
    "license": "12344",
    "books": [
    ]
  },
  {
    "storename": "store 3",
    "license": "12344",
    "books": [

    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please include your code, and tell us what *specifically* is the problem with that code. As it stands, the post reads more like a to-do than a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spite of original array does not contain any knockout:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "storename": "store 1",
    "license": "12314",
    "books": [
      "abc",
      "def",
      "cdf"
    ]
  },
  {
    "storename": "store 2",
    "license": "12344",
    "books": [
      "dfd",
      "eww"
    ]
  },
  {
    "storename": "store 3",
    "license": "12344",
    "books": [

    ]
  }
];

function ViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.filter = ko.observable("a");
  self.items = ko.computed(function() {
    return data.filter(function(item) {
      return ko.unwrap(item.books).some(function(book) { return book.indexOf(self.filter()) !== -1; });
    });
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

```css
.store-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span>Filter text: </span><input data-bind="value: filter, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<div>Search results:</div>
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<div class="store-item">
<span>Store name: </span><span data-bind="text: storename"></span>
<br>
<span>License: </span><span data-bind="text: license"></span>
<br>
<!-- ko foreach: books -->
<span>Book: </span><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<br>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>  
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this surely helped me.. however i need output in which all the stores will be listed and books which matches filter text will be listed under the stores..